# Difference between position of elements of GUI before and after open it in GUIDE in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I'm designing a GUI with GUIDE. When I open a window in GUIDE and after that run it, position of elements like panels,radio buttons and etc are difference with when I run MATLAB and directly run a GUI from `.m file`. It is a confusing problem because the real positions are that I'm running from `.m file`.

All elements of the window are nearly 1 cm to the right compared to when running it directly and I have a little vertical difference between these two. I should design a window and after that close MATLAB and run it directly to see the real positions! If I directly open it from `.m file` after using GUIDE, there isn't any difference with running from GUIDE and run from `.m file`. I have to restart MATLAB to see the difference.

What is your idea about this problem? How can I solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Idea 1

This is more of a workaround rather than a solution:

What you could do, after positioning all elements in GUIDE, is to export the figure to an `.m` file (you don't actually need the `.fig` in order to have an interactive figure) using the menubar option `File > Export ...` in GUIDE.

This way you'll get an `.m` file with all the elements' positions hardcoded. If you change the position values from that file, there is **absolutely no chance** that they'll appear someplace else.

#### Idea 2

Try setting the `Resize behavior` of the GUI to `Non-resizable`. This is accessible from the GUIDE menu by `Tools > GUI Options...`

Comment: Thank you for answer but didn't solve the problem. I checked your first idea and created a single `.m` file. In GUIDE everything is good but when I run `.m` file all elements 1cm righter than normal position. In this case when I rerun MATLAB there isn't any different. Good positions in GUIDE and bad positions in running from `.m` file. I think there is a bug in GUIDE.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your interface in GUIDE? I suspect your problem has something to do with the margins' sizes. BTW, why can't you just select everything and move it 1cm to the left?

Comment: Yes. I'm doing it now in my works but I'm searching for any solution. It is a little hard rerun MATLAB to see the effects of changing positions. I have different situation and position changing in every window. I added a screenshot.